# How to adjust bash file to execute on a single node

Tags: bash, matlab

I would like your help to know whether it is possible (and if yes how) to adjust the bash file below.

---

I have a principal Matlab script `main.m`, which in turn calls another Matlab script `f.m`.

`f.m` should be executed many times with different inputs.

I structure this as an array job.

I typically use the following bash file called `td.sh` to execute the array job into the HPC of my university

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=5G
#$ -l tmem=5G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 237 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 237
#$ -t 1-237

#$ -N mod
date
hostname

#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

/share/[...]/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

What I do in the terminal is

- `cd` to the folder where the scripts `main.m`, `f.m`, `td.sh` are located
- type in the terminal `qsub td.sh`

---

**Question:** I need to change the bash file above because the script `f.m` calls a solver (Gurobi) whose license is single node single user. This is what I have been told:

" *This license has been installed already and works only on node `A`. 
You will not be able to `qsub` your scripts as the jobs have to run on this node.
Instead you should `ssh` into node `A` and run the job on this node directly instead
of submitting to the scheduler*. "

Could you guide me through understanding how I should change the bash file above? In particular, how should I force the execution into node `A`?

Even though I am restricted to one node only, am I still able to parallelise using array jobs? Or array jobs are by definition executed on multiple nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use your scheduler, then you cannot use its array jobs. You will have to find another way to parallelize those jobs. Array jobs are not executed on multiple nodes by definition (but they are usually executed on multiple nodes due to resource availability).

Regarding the adaptation of your script, just follow the guidelies provided by your sysadmins: forget about SGE and start your calculus through ssh directly against the node you have been told:

```
date
hostname

for TASK_ID in {1..237}
do
    #Output the Task ID
    echo "Task ID is $TASK_ID"

    ssh user@A "/share/[...]/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r \"main; ID = $TASK_ID; f; exit\""
done
```

If the license is single node and single user (but multiple simultaneous execution), you can try to parallelize the calculus. You will have to take into account the resources available in the node A (number of CPUs, memory...) and the resources that you need for every single execution, and then start simultaneously as many calculus as possible without overloading the node (otherwise they will take longer or even fail).

Comment: Thanks. When you say `If the license is single node and single user (but multiple simultaneous execution), you can try to parallelize the calculus [...]`, do you mean using `parfor` for example?

Comment: But this means that I am very limited on how many parallel workers I can use, correct?

Comment: You can user any paralellization method you want: `parfor`, `parallel`, the bash job monitor system... Up to you. Regarding the limit on parallel workers you can use... the limit is imposed by the license and the hardware. If you can run on a single node, only the workers that fit in that node. The bigger the node, the more workers it can handle.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted your answer. I have other doubts related to parallelisation (sorry, I'm a very beginner) but I'll ask them in a separate question.